# Ubuntu 12.04 having strange issue with WPA2/Enterprise

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, broadcom

I'm pretty new to Ubuntu and I'm not sure that I'm going to state all the necessary information, so please don't hesitate to ask me for more.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my Dell Latitude E5430. My wireless card is a `BCM4313 802.11bgn`.

At my university I've got a strange issue with the wireless network. They use WPA2/Entrprise with PEAP authentication. These are the specific settings that I'm using based on what they said on their support website:

```
Security: WPA & WPA2 Enterprise

Authentication: Protected EAP PEAP)

Anonymous Identity: [blank]

Inner Authentication: MSCHAPv2

Username: []
Password:[]
```

I found [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2059808) related article and followed the steps listed with no luck. The strange thing is that I get a valid IP address, but when I open a browser and try to go to a website it will just sit there until it times out.

**UPDATE**
I ended up trying to update to 13.04 (which I love by the way) hoping it would alleviate the problem. Unfortunately, I'm still having the same issue. Hopefully someone can help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this bug is listed at [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-applet/+bug/1104476).

The solution worked for me. Run the terminal and type:

```
sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/CONNECTION__NAME
```

In gedit window remove "system-ca-certs=true" or modify "true" to "false".